# Powershell: IdentityNotMappedException when the user does exist when trying to update ownership for network folder

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

By the way, I am new to powershell.

I'm trying to fix permissions and ownership that a previous admin has severely messed up.
We have a network share that we use for Folder Redirects in AD. We also have 3 DCs on premises.

I already fixed the user permissions on the shared folder and sub directories. What I have left is to fix the ownership of the folders as they are all owned by the previous admin and these are used for the HOME of the users.

I have been working on a script that I thought would only take an hour but now it's been 4 and this is really confusing me.

This is my script:

```
$sharedDir = '\\Jupiter\Users'

# Loop over shared directory to process each directory
Get-ChildItem $sharedDir|foreach-object {
    # Directories are usernames
    $userName = $_.Name
    $userDir = $_.FullName

    try {
        Write-Host 'Processing: ' $userName

        # Get AD Details for the user with properties
        $adDetails = Get-ADUser -Identity $userName -Properties *

        # Check if the user is enabled
        if ($adDetails.Enabled -eq $FALSE) {
            Write-Host '- is disabled'
            Write-Host '- Skipped'
        } else {
            Write-Host '- is ENABLED'
            # Fetch ACL for the directory            
            $acl = $null; # Reset
            $acl = Get-Acl -Path $userDir

            # Fetch the current ownership
            $ownership = $acl.sddl -replace 'o:(.+?)G:.+','$1'
            
            # Check if ownership matches
            if ($ownership -eq $adDetails.SID) {
                Write-Host '- Has correct ownership'
                Write-Host '- Skipped'
            } else {
                Write-Host '- Need to fix ownership'


                $objSID = New-Object 'Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier' $adDetails.SID 

                # Fix ownership
                #$objUser = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList ($sid)
                #$acl.SetOwner($objSID)
                $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("FFGROUP", $userName);
                $acl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference]$objUser)
                Set-Acl -Path $userDir -AclObject $acl
                
                
                Write-Host $userDir
                Write-Host $adDetails.SID

                Get-ACL -Path $userDir

                exit # Only do this one for now
            }

        }

    } catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        # User does not exist handling
        Write-Host '- Does not exist.'
        Write-Host '- Skipped'
    }
    
    # Sanity seperator
    Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------'

}
```

Example output:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Processing:  ClaudiaO
- is ENABLED
- Has correct ownership
- Skipped
--------------------------------------------------
Processing:  ClaudiaV
- Does not exist.
- Skipped
--------------------------------------------------
Processing:  Conference
- is ENABLED
- Need to fix ownership
Set-Acl : Some or all identity references could not be translated.
At \\jupiter\Users\Jeremy\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\fixPermissionsOnUsersDirectory.ps1:46 char:17
+                 Set-Acl -Path $userDir -AclObject $acl
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (\\Jupiter\Users\Conference:String) [Set-Acl], IdentityNotMappedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

From my understanding, this means it can't find the user. The user does exist. It does this to every user.

What can I do to fix just the ownership? What is missing so that it can find the user? I am already fetching the user with `Get-ADUser` so why is it giving `IdentityNotMappedException` ?

I have tried by using SID and the username. I found about 5 different methods to create these and all do not work. I always get this error. I thought I may need to point it to a DC but couldn't figure out how.

I am a Domain Admin and have full control. I do not have any permission issues when accessing this share and this script is running from my user.

This is an emergency, so I am working on this while I manually fix a few hundred directories. Any help is gratefully appreciated!

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceSids, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.Translate(Type targetType)
at System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity.GetOwner(Type targetType)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.SetSecurityDescriptor(String path, ObjectSecurity securityDescriptor)
at System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal.SetSecurityDescriptor(CmdletProvider providerInstance, String path, ObjectSecurity securityDescriptor, CmdletProviderContext context)
```

Comment: Yes, `FFGROUP` is the domain name. The FQDN is `ffgroup.local`. Our users are `FFGROUP\UserName`

Comment: same error if you just set the user's SID? `$acl.SetOwner($adDetails.SID)`

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: It might help debugging this if you add the output from `$Error[0].Exception.StackTrace` after hitting that error

Comment: Updated post to include that

Comment: 2 questions: 1. is powershell running elevated (run as admin) ? 2. what's your powershell version? (`$PSVersionTable`)

Comment: My powershell version is: `5.1.22621.2506` I have tried elevated and non-elevated. Same issue both ways. Same issue with PowerShell `7.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't see you doing something wrong in your code which leads me to believe the issue is `Set-Acl`. Perhaps using [`SetAccessControl` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1) directly might solve this issue. Here is how your code should look using the .NET APIs directly:

```bash
$sharedDir = '\\Jupiter\Users'
$ownerSids = @{}
Get-ChildItem $sharedDir | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Write-Host "- Processing: '$($_.Name)'"
        $adDetails = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Name

        # Check if the user is enabled
        if (-not $adDetails.Enabled) {
            Write-Host "- '$($_.Name)' is disabled. Skipped"
            return # => nothing to do here, go to next item in loop
        }

        Write-Host "- '$($_.Name)' is ENABLED"

        # Fetch ACL for the directory
        $acl = $_.GetAccessControl([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::Owner)

        # if this owner's SID is not cached
        if (-not $ownerSids.ContainsKey($acl.Owner)) {
            # cache the SID for this user, this is mainaly for efficiency
            # avoids unnecessary translations
            try {
                $sid = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]::new($acl.Owner).
                    Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
            }
            catch {
                # if this NTAccount couldn't be translated, assume the Identity doesn't exist
                $sid = $null
            }

            $ownerSids[$acl.Owner] = $sid
        }

        # Check if ownership matches
        if ($ownerSids[$acl.Owner] -eq $adDetails.SID) {
            Write-Host "- '$($_.Name)' Has correct ownership. Skipped"
            return # => nothing to do here, go to next item in loop
        }

        Write-Host "- Need to fix ownership for '$($_.Name)'"

        $acl.SetOwner($adDetails.SID)
        # if this is a file, we need to use the `File.SetAccessControl` API
        if ($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
            [System.IO.File]::SetAccessControl($_.FullName, $acl)
            return
        }
        # else, this is a directory, so `Directory.SetAccessControl`
        [System.IO.Directory]::SetAccessControl($_.FullName, $acl)
    }
    catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {
        # User does not exist handling
        Write-Host "- '$($_.TargetObject)' Does not exist. Skipped"
    }

    # Sanity seperator
    Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------'
}
```

Comment: @Jeremy hopefully it helps now

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked but it seemed way too fast. One user has a very large directory, over 500GB and it was done in 1 second. It looks correct but when I do it manually, through the UI it took 4 hours. I will do more testing but this seems to have solved my issue entirely!

Comment: @Jeremy eyyy thats awesome ! glad it was helpful useful. perhaps the speed is because you're not traversing all files in your file share (you might need to use `-Recurse`). In .NET (and PowerShell in consequence), when setting an ACL it doesn't automatically cascade down. You need to apply ACLs to all the hierarchy, even if inheritance is enabled. But don't take my word for it, double check it yourself. As aside, if possible, could we clear the comment section of this answer ?